# Fill intent based on result of API call in Dialogflow Fullfilment

Tags: javascript, callback, dialogflow-es

I am struggling to get the following fullfilment code for Dialogflow to work:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function testHandler(agent){
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    var theUrl = "http://xxxxx/sum?a=5&b=11";
    var url = proxyurl + theUrl;
    var result = "Init";

    getText = function(url, callback)
    {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onload = function()
      {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
        {
          callback(request.responseText);
        }
      };
      request.open('GET', url);
      request.send();
    }

    function mycallback(data) {
      agent.add("DATA:" + data);
    }

    return getText(url, mycallback);
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('test', testHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

The line `agent.add("DATA:" + data);` does not have any effect. When trying the code in the browsers and changing `agent.add("DATA:" + data)` to `document.write("DATA:" + data)`, everything works just fine. 
I am new to Dialogflow; any hint why this callback does not seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing asynchronous operations (such as making network API calls), your Intent Handler **must** return a Promise, so the Handler Dispatcher knows to wait for the response from the API before sending the response to the user. In your case, when the response comes back, it does try to send it to the user, but since a response was already sent (with nothing) nobody sees it.

Your web browser is handling everything locally, so you don't see the same issues (even tho it is doing the same sort of thing).

While you can probably wrap your code in a Promise, the easier way is to use something like [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) to do your HTTP call, do the call to `agent.add()` in the `then()` block, and return the overall promise. Something like this, perhaps:

```
  function testHandlerPromise(agent){
    const rp = require('request-promise-native');

    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    var theUrl = "http://xxxxx/sum?a=5&b=11";
    var url = proxyurl + theUrl;

    return rp( url ).then( data => {
      agent.add("DATA:" + data);
    } );
  }
```

Comment: Cool. After having added the appropriate headers (`'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`), it is working like a breeze now. Thanks.